# Rails with ruby-debugger throw 'Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread (LoadError)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

I have standard ruby-head and Rails 3.1rc4.
I installed ruby-debug  with following instructions from http://dirk.net/2010/04/17/ruby-debug-with-ruby-19x-and-rails-3-on-rvm/

But when i run `rails s --debugger` it will throw this strange error

```
/Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require': dlopen(/Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.bundle - /Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.bundle
from /Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `block in require'
from /Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
```

Any idea?
Thanks, David

Comment: Did you ever work it out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: It is long time ago. I think problem was in ruby version. I had some edge of 1.9.2 and that was problem. Now I run on `ruby 1.9.2p180` and it is ok. I reinstalled whole ruby, rvm, gems cause really big mess in it after few years of using :)

Comment: I'm getting the same error in 1.9.3-preview1

Comment: Same error is 1.9.3-p0

Answer (score 54, accepted):

UPDATE:

Looks like you only need to put this in your gemfile:

gem "debugger"

and now works.

Old article follows

====================================

Jerome is correct, but lacking in the details. Here is the blow by blow, taken from this https://gist.github.com/1331533, in particular thanks to andrewroth's post. I've tested this as of the time of this post. One hopes that the changes will be deployed somewhere standard soon.

```
Installing ruby debugger on ruby 1.9.3-p125: 

export PATCH_LEVEL=`ruby -e 'puts RUBY_PATCHLEVEL'`
export RVM_SRC=$HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p$PATCH_LEVEL/include/ruby-1.9.1
gem install archive-tar-minitar
gem install ruby_core_source -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
export RVM_SRC=$HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p$PATCH_LEVEL/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p$PATCH_LEVEL

wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75415/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/63094/ruby-debug19-0.11.6.gem
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
# if that step failed, and you are running OSX Lion, then following this post can help you: 
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues
# this happens if you recently installed xcode from the app store. 
# bizarrely, for me I had to do this: ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC

Then edit Gemfile: 

gem 'linecache19', '0.5.13', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}/gems/linecache19-0.5.13/"
gem 'ruby-debug-base19', '0.11.26', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26/"
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

Then install: 

bundle install
```

Comment: I did everything in Rob's post, but the gem installs failed.  I had to do the following in the directory where the gem was downloaded:

rvm 1.9.3-p0@mygemset do gem install ~/Downloads/linecache19-0.5.13.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/Users/<your_user_name>/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0

        rvm 1.9.3-p0@mygemset do gem install ~/Downloads/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/Users/<your_user_name>/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0


        I'm running OSX Lion 10.7.3

Comment: I did everything in Rob's post, but the gem installs failed. I had to do the following in the directory where the gem was downloaded: rvm 1.9.3-p0@mygemset do gem install ~/Downloads/linecache19-0.5.13.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/Users/<your_user_name>/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 rvm 1.9.3-p0@mygemset do gem install ~/Downloads/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/Users/<your_user_name>/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 I'm running OSX Lion 10.7.3

Comment: After a good bit of going back and forth with different blog posts on how to get debugger working this did the trick :)

Comment: @seanmrafferty - you were right, I missed the wget for linecache gem, added that and updated for 1.9.3-p125

Comment: Good tip. I successfully start with debugger with above instructions. thanks!

Comment: trying to understand --with-ruby-include what is that for? and why do we need different RVM_SRC for different packages? thanks...

Comment: I just had to switch to `gem 'debugger'` in my Gemfile, and I'm running again. Mac OS X Lion, ruby 1.9.3-p125

Comment: this worked for me, but I had to remove gem "ruby-debug19" from the Gemfile

Answer (score 21):

I used the [gem 'debugger'](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) which is a fork of ruby-debug(19) that works on 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 and installs easily for rvm/rbenv rubies.
It makes the error disappear !

Comment: It worked for me too...  thanks. Using `ruby 1.9.3p0` from rvm in OSX

Answer (score 11):

It looks like this is a known bug in ruby-debug-base, for the moment. I have added my comment to the issue on the bug tracker. Plase consider adding your notes as well:

http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29222&group_id=8883&atid=34290

In the meantime, ruby 1.9 has a built-in debugger; its just **very** slow. Manually add this require line to your code:

```
require 'debug'
```

Also, the debugger breaks on all StandardError exceptions by default, so do this when it first starts up:

```
catch off
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are running Ruby 1.9.3x, to fix it go to [ruby-debug on rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-debug19/), download and install ruby-debug-base 0.11.26 and linecache19 0.5.13. Modify your Gemfile to use these files, then run

```
bundle update ruby-debug-base19
```

Debugger should work now.

Thanks
Jerome

Comment: ruby-debug-base19 v 0.11.26 did not compile on my system (with rvm). I had to add the ruby includes to make it compile: gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p0/

Comment: Did not work for me, the update went fine but still same error :( Error Output: 
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta8, ruby-debug-base 0.11.30.pre7) listens on 127.0.0.1:60534

Comment: This work for me gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/Users/jirapong/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 . take from https://gist.github.com/1331533

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed upgrading to the latest gems of all debug

Comment: Still not working for me. What version of ruby-debug19 and linecache19 are you using that works?

Comment: These are in my dev group: you won't need them all check versions for the debug ones: group :development do
  gem "sunspot_solr" # optional pre-packaged Solr distribution for use in development
  gem "annotate"
  gem "faker"
  gem "populator"
  gem "erb2haml"
  gem "foreman"
  gem "progress_bar"
  gem "simplecov"
  gem "ruby-debug19"
  gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '0.11.30.pre10'
  gem "ruby-debug-ide", '0.4.17.beta8'
  #gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem "capistrano"
  gem "bundler"
end

Answer (score 0):

Using ruby 1.9.3, I was able to get this to work by adding the gem 'ruby-debug-base19x' (note the 'x' at the end of the name) in addition to 'ruby-debug19'.

Answer (score 0):

My system is rvm 1.18.10 and ruby 1.9.3p392 on Mac OSX 10.8.5. I first installed gem 'ruby-debug19', but for the well-known reason, the debugger did not work.

I then ran

```
local$ gem install 'debugger'
```

as suggested by many other posts. The gem was installed successfully with the following outputs:

```
local$ gem install debugger
Fetching: debugger-ruby_core_source-1.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: debugger-linecache-1.2.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: debugger-1.6.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed debugger-ruby_core_source-1.2.3
Successfully installed debugger-linecache-1.2.0
Successfully installed debugger-1.6.2
3 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for debugger-ruby_core_source-1.2.3...
Installing ri documentation for debugger-linecache-1.2.0...
Installing ri documentation for debugger-1.6.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for debugger-ruby_core_source-1.2.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for debugger-linecache-1.2.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for debugger-1.6.2...
local$ irb
1.9.3-p392 :002 > require 'debugger'
=> true
```

I then ran

```
local$ rails server --debug
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:
in`require': dlopen(/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle,
9): Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread (LoadError)
Referenced from: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
......
```

I resolved this error by commenting out the line "gem 'ruby-debug19'" and adding a new line "gem 'debugger'" in the Gemfile, and then ran

```
local$ bundle update
```

After that, everything worked fine.

```
local$ rails server --debug
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.14 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
=> Debugger enabled
[2013-10-15 12:50:21] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-10-15 12:50:21] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-22) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
[2013-10-15 12:50:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7206 port=3000
```