# rake db:seed failing on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake-task, seeding

Can some one make sense of this output? Its been a very long day and my eyes are glazing over. Yesterday it seemed to work fine.

```
rake db:seed --trace
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- ruby-debug

/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
/home/cooperative/apps/cooperative/releases/20120801010134/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/cooperative/apps/cooperative/releases/20120801010134/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/cooperative/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Thank you John for editing my post. One of these days I must learn the proper posting format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just updated Ruby to 1.9.3, and there are apparently some issues between that and ruby-debug. For details on how to (maybe) make it work, see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/431168.

Comment: I was aware of that problem when I wanted to use debug in development and I installed linecache19 (0.5.13) from rubyforge. Can't understand why db:seed needs debug on the production server. I have ruby-debug only in the development group. If I move it global group then capistrano won't even finish complaining that it cannot find the linecache19 gem. Sort of a catch22 situation.

Comment: Regarding why db:seed needs debug -- in the shell where you're working, is RAILS_ENV set to "production", or are you running `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed`? If not, then the task will execute with the development environment and require all the gems in the :development group.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I decided to use bundle package and check all the gems into the repo. I'll see if it solves the problem if I do a bundle install -local on the server.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the ruby-debug gem is not installed, use bundle install to before run the rake db:seed.

Make sure its included in gem file. please check [ruby-debug19 on ruby-1.9.3-preview1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054948/ruby-debug19-on-ruby-1-9-3-preview1), it may help you.