# Cannot use ruby-debug19 with 1.9.3-p0?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, ruby-debug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.3p125: ruby-debug19 still crashes with “Symbol not found: _ruby_threadptr_data_type”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442200/rails-3-1-and-ruby-1-9-3p125-ruby-debug19-still-crashes-with-symbol-not-found)

I run this:

`gem install ruby-debug19`

And in my cucumber `env.rb` file, I have this:

`require 'ruby-debug'`

When I try to run, though, I get this exception:

`/home/skendall/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread - /home/skendall/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so (LoadError)`

What do I need to do to get ruby-debug to work with 1.9.3-p0?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10414984/773690

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### UPDATE: ruby-debug19 is not maintained anymore. This question and my answer have become irrelevant, it's far easier to use the 'debugger' gem instead.

### See [Debugging in ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9)

I also ran into this, and found the solution in [Ruby 1.9.3 and ruby-debug](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug). You need to install not-yet-officially-released versions of ruby-debug-base19 and linecache19. The currently released versions indeed cause the exception you had.

Use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1331533).

```
#To install ruby-debug on Ubuntu ruby-1.9.3 you need to download from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883

linecache19-0.5.13.gem 
ruby_core_source-0.1.5.gem 
ruby-debug19-0.11.6.gem 
ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem

#Then in your console

export RVM_SRC=/your/path/to/ruby-1.9.3
# Note, your source path should be something like /home/user/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0

gem install archive-tar-minitar
gem install ruby_core_source-0.1.5.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
gem install ruby-debug19-0.11.6.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
```

Comment: I added the full set of instructions in case any of the links die.

Comment: And I tried to follow these directions today, had trouble with version numbers, etc, and wrote up the updated procedure on this other SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9267541/399346. You might find it even easier to follow

Comment: The important parts I think are requiring correct versions.  This in my Gemfile may help:   gem 'linecache19', '~> 0.5.13'
  gem 'ruby-debug-base19', '~> 0.11.26'
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

Comment: Well, I get: `Could not find gem 'ruby-debug-base19 (~> 0.11.26) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.`

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug. There's reportedly some work arounds [here](http://blog.sj26.com/post/10263431961/using-ruby-debug-on-ruby-1-9-3-preview1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054948/ruby-debug19-on-ruby-1-9-3-preview1) and finally [here](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug).

Answer (score 3):

If the workarounds are annoying and/or impossible due to your rvm/bundler setup, which is the case with me, consider [pry](http://pry.github.com/), and optionally the [pry-debug plugin](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry_debug). Pry might be a more generally useful tool than ruby-debug anyways.