# Using ruby-debug with rails 3.1.1 and ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

I have read tutorials and several stack overflow posts that suggest I should use

```
gem 'ruby-debug19', "~> 0.11.6"
```

or
    gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug', :platforms => :mri_19
    gem 'ruby-debug', :platforms => :mri_18

After doing a bundle install, I attempt to use this by executing

```
rails s --debugger
```

and get the error message

```
"You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug' Exiting
```

if I type

```
gem install ruby-debug
```

I get:  ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
    rbx-require-relative requires Ruby version ~> 1.8.7.

```
gem install ruby-debug19
```

does execute, but still the error message above is reported when I attempt to start the server.

I must be missing something obvious, because there are no other comments on the original stack overflow question.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the line `gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'` in your Gemfile should do. Then run `bundle install`

Comment: Thong, I added the line as you suggest.  Then after bundle install I enter  $ rails server --debugger   and get the following error:

    /Users/oblinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': dlopen(/Users/oblinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/oblinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Comment: ah, right. Ruby 1.9.3 has problems with ruby-debug. Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378306/800526