# RVM, Ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.1.3: can't start rails server due to ruby-debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, ruby-debug, ruby-1.9.3

When I try to start the rails server via `rails s` I get this error:

```
/home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `require': /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread - /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so (LoadError)
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `require'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `require'
    from /home/james/rails-projs/macedonia_nato/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'    
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem 'redis'
gem 'haml'

gem 'aws-s3'


gem 'braintree'
gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement', :require => 'ssl_requirement'

gem 'paperclip'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'vanity', :git => 'git://github.com/mrpersister/vanity.git'
```

I've been google-ing around and I can't figure it out. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378277/cannot-use-ruby-debug19-with-1-9-3-p0

Answer (score 10):

Add these lines to Gemfile:

```
gem 'linecache19', :git => 'git://github.com/mark-moseley/linecache'
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '~> 0.11.30.pre4'
gem 'ruby-debug19'
```

And do bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

Since ruby-debug19 is not supported any longer, see [Debugging in ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9).

You will now need to replace

> gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

with

> gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

That should do the trick.