# Error on db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to modify a rails app built on an another computer ,I ran bundle install
and all gems got installed.But when I run rake db:migrate ,it throws down a bunch of errors ,I am new to rail and cant understand what those error messages

```
rake aborted!
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread -     /home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `require'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `require'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
/home/diadara/hw3_rottenpotatoes/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/diadara/hw3_rottenpotatoes/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/diadara/hw3_rottenpotatoes/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/diadara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@saasrails3.1/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you show your migrations? That would probably clear a lot up for others to answer your question. One more question: Are you trying to use ruby-debug19 in development mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you did not properly install ruby-debug in your project. remove it from the gemfile if it is not needed or have a look at this answer to fix it: [Cannot use ruby-debug19 with 1.9.3-p0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378277/cannot-use-ruby-debug19-with-1-9-3-p0)