# Ruby on rails legacy application error with linecache gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ruby on rails legacy application and I have the following error when I run the application

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.so (LoadError)
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/tracelines19.rb:12:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/tracelines19.rb:12:in `rescue in <module:TraceLineNumbers>'
```

Full error can be found [Here](http://msl1.it.kth.se/Melange2)

Could anyone help me spot the problem?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378277/cannot-use-ruby-debug19-with-1-9-3-p0

Comment: I appreciate the effort to relate to possible duplicates.  I am looking for a solution I already stumbled upon them and they did not work. @DamienRoche The link to ruby source is dead in that post.

Comment: @j-dexx Sorry but that didn't solve my problem. I posted my solution below thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linecache has a patched gem to work with ruby-debug

add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'linecache19-patched' instead of 
gem  'linecache19'
```