# bundle install circular dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, bundle

The following console logs should describe the issue

```
bundle install
Could not find multi_json-1.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

bundle install asks me to bundle install.

Have tried: https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler/issues/4 
Looked at: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/865

Not sure where to go next.

Also of interest, if we comment all the gems from inside vendor/gems the bundle works fine.

source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.2'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'thin'

# Asset template engines
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'less-js'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'lucy'
gem 'babilu'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mechanize'
gem 'geoip'
gem 'less'
gem 'bb-ruby'
gem 'client_side_validations', "~> 3.2.0.beta.2"
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'
gem 'require_all'

#for avatars
gem 'paperclip'

gem 'rmagick'
gem "multipart-post"
gem 'gibberish'
# Memcached client
gem 'dalli'

#to support tables without auto-incrementing primary keys
gem 'composite_primary_keys', "~> 5.0.1"

gem 'calendar_helper', :require => 'calendar_helper'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-ext'

gem 'simple_form'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'will_paginate'

gem 'airbrake', :path => "vendor/gems/airbrake"

gem "uservoice", :path => "vendor/gems/uservoice"

# For spambots
gem "honeypot-captcha"

# Internationalization GUI
gem "tolk", :git => "http://github.com/miloops/tolk.git", :branch => "rails31"
gem "will-paginate-i18n"

gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-facebook"
gem "omniauth-justintv", :git => 'http://github.com/themindoverall/omniauth-justintv.git'
gem 'oauth'

gem 'rails-i18n'

# For rate limiting
gem "rack-throttle", :path => "vendor/gems/rack-throttle"

gem "xfire-api", :path => "vendor/gems/xfire-api"
gem "anametrix", :path => "vendor/gems/anametrix"

#To make ruby debug work see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438116/rails-with-ruby-debugger-throw-symbol-not-found-ruby-current-thread-loaderro
group :development, :test do
  #gem 'ruby-debug-base19', '0.11.26', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26/"
  #gem 'linecache19', '0.5.13', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}/gems/linecache19-0.5.13/"
  #gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
end

group :test do
  gem 'ruby-prof'
  gem 'test-unit' # For performance testing

  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 1.0.1"
  gem 'capybara', "~> 1.0.0"
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.6.7'

  gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.6.1"
  gem 'cucumber-rails', "~> 1.0.0"
  gem 'webrat', "~> 0.7.3"
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'autotest-rails-pure'

    gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test
  gem 'spork'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rack-google_analytics', :require => "rack/google_analytics"
end
```

Comment: please place the gem inside your gemfile & do `bundle update` & try

Comment: Been down that path. No go. The gem it fails on is whichever the next gem it still needs to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone turns out to be stuck on this what turned out to be the answer is one of our homegrown gems:

gem "xfire-api", :path => "vendor/gems/xfire-api"

had a require in it provided by a gem that was not specified in the gemspec. If you're stuck on this and have homegrown gems take a look through all your requires and makes sure all the files are provided by gems you specify in the Gemspec.

Comment: just wonering what are you using anametrix for

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared that gem in your `Gemfile`? Sometimes it helps to specify a specific version as you've done for some:

```
gem 'multi-json', '1.1.0'
```

Comment: Played with that. No go. It's not specifically that gem, that was just the first gem that happened to needing updating. Blowing away the vendored bundle on the server then asks for rake instead of multi-json. It's just whatever happens to be the first gem that needs installing.