# Can't install Debugger gem - Rails - Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I'm trying to run an app locally but when I do I get thrown this error.

```
Patricks-MacBook-Air:niet pbj$ rails s
Could not find debugger-1.6.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I run 'bundle install' I get this:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.0) 
Using atomic (1.1.13) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.25) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0) 
Using addressable (2.3.5) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using mini_portile (0.5.1) 
Using nokogiri (1.6.0) 
Using uuidtools (2.1.4) 
Using aws-sdk (1.11.1) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1) 
Using coderay (1.0.9) 
Using better_errors (0.9.0) 
Using debug_inspector (0.0.2) 
Using binding_of_caller (0.7.2) 
Using sass (3.2.10) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using bourbon (3.1.8) 
Using callsite (0.0.11) 
Using cancan (1.6.10) from https://github.com/ricec/cancan.git (at master) 
Using xpath (2.0.0) 
Using capybara (2.1.0) 
Using climate_control (0.0.3) 
Using cocaine (0.5.1) 
Using columnize (0.3.6) 
Using database_cleaner (1.1.1) 
Using debugger-linecache (1.2.0) 
Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3) 
Installing debugger (1.6.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... no
Makefile creation failed
*************************************************************

  NOTE: If your headers were not found, try passing
        --with-ruby-include=PATH_TO_HEADERS      

*************************************************************

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include
    --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/pbj/.bundler/tmp/39109/gems/debugger-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/pbj/.bundler/tmp/39109/gems/debugger-1.6.1/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After that I try and install the debugger gem and get this error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debugger:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... no
Makefile creation failed
*************************************************************

  NOTE: If your headers were not found, try passing
        --with-ruby-include=PATH_TO_HEADERS      

*************************************************************

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include
    --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/debugger-1.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/debugger-1.6.2/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
```

At this point I have absolutely no clue how to resolve the issue.

Comment: try to add gem 'debugger' in your Gemfile

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry, but I'm that new to this whole thing.

Comment: Debugger doesn't work with Ruby 2.0, which is the default on Mavericks.  You should install byebug instead, or RubyMine.

Comment: was having the same issue, did a bit of digging and found this - http://levimccallum.com/post/64893573116/compiling-ruby-debugger-gem-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks but the suggested command comes back with an error saying the selected software is unavailable from the download server. Hope that helps someone get a litter further along

Answer (score 6):

This is XCode 5.1's problem. Just try the following:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install GEMNAME
```

Then, you can install it successfully.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have the right ruby version "ruby -v" or if you are using rvm make sure you switch to the right version "rvm use 2.0". Otherwise, put more information about your current ruby and rails versions and are you using rvm or system ruby, etc

Answer (score 0):

Mavericks's default ruby2.0 headers are out of place.  Try installing your own ruby, manually or through a version manager like rbenv, and try running it again.

---

You can check by running

```
which ruby
```

If the output is

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Then it's probably using the system ruby

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not pretty. I know it will feel dirty. I don't like downloading gems I'm not going to use. But this worked for me.

I have experienced the same problem on 2 different machines plus my own with bundler trying to get debugger 1.6.0 with ruby 1.7.3 (and a few other gems). It refused to download and getting it manually did not work either. I stumbled on a work-a-round by trying to install other versions to see if it was a problem with the version. What ended up working (and I do not know why it works) is that I ran “bundle update”, then “git checkout .” to revert the gemlock file, then run “bundle install”. This has worked every time for me.

This is a guess but I think “bundle install” sorts the list of gems to download and stops at the first one that throws an error so following dependencies do not download. When running “bundle update” it goes through the list and gets latest version so if an error is thrown then it reports the error. So if there is some type circular dependency in the gem this would fix it because would get the dependency or a workable version that was causing the problem. *I can not find proof that this is even possible*.

Similar issue:
[bundle install circular dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831636/bundle-install-circular-dependencies)